# R - Interpreting results of prop.test with different alternative hypothesis

Tags: r, statistical-significance, proportion

I am using `prop.test` in R to test if two proportions are equal and if not, which is bigger. (I'm not sure if it's pertinent to the problem, but as you can see the proportions are very small.)

I am trying to understand why I am getting an extremely small p-value for two different alternative hypothesis for two identical samples (sample `A` and sample `B`):

```
#               A    B       A       B
> prop.test(c(2842, 74), c(222380, 797083))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(2842, 74) out of c(222380, 797083)
X-squared = 9808.1, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01221689 0.01315729
sample estimates:
      prop 1       prop 2 
1.277993e-02 9.283851e-05
```

and

```
#               A    B       A       B
> prop.test(c(2842, 74), c(222380, 797083), alternative = "greater")

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(2842, 74) out of c(222380, 797083)
X-squared = 9808.1, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: greater
95 percent confidence interval:
0.01229202 1.00000000
sample estimates:
  prop 1       prop 2 
1.277993e-02 9.283851e-05
```

Isn't the first saying that A and B are the same (p < 2.2e-16) and the second is saying A is greater than B (p < 2.2e-16)?

If so how can this be true? If not, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what the first test tells you. Further, given a rejection, you don't need a second test to tell which one you'd conclude is greater. *Just look at the proportions* and you'll see why the first null was rejected. (Incidentally, faced with that table of numbers I wouldn't have bothered with actually calculating a p-value. It's obviously so small that any attempt at an actual p-value calculation is pointless - what would be the value in it?)

Comment: Yes I figured this out and explained it in the answers.

Answer (score -1):

I was using two groups which tests that they are NOT equal if no alternative hypothesis is supplied.

> If there are two groups, the alternatives are that the probability of success in the first group is less than, not equal to, or greater than the probability of success in the second group, as specified by alternative.